# NSFetchedResultsController in iOS10 / Swift 3 - Still error message after conversion

Tags: swift, swift3, ios10

I'm converting swift app to 3.0 and there is one issue left. I have read all instructions that NSFetchedResultController is now generic and modified the code but still getting the infamous "semicolon" error.

Original code:

```
    fileprivate lazy var jobController:NSFetchedResultsController = { () -> <<error type>> in 
        let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: AGJobData.entityName)
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "jobNumber", ascending: true), NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]
        let controller = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: AGDataManager.sharedManager.managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        var error:NSError? = nil
        controller.performFetch(&error)
        controller.delegate = self
        return controller
        }()
```

Modified by me (manually, XCode convertor did not touch this piece of code):

```
    fileprivate lazy var jobController:NSFetchedResultsController<AGJobData>= { () -> <<error type>> in
    let request = NSFetchRequest<AGJobData>()
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "jobNumber", ascending: true), NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]
    let controller = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: AGDataManager.sharedManager.managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    var error:NSError? = nil
    controller.performFetch(&error)
    controller.delegate = self
    return controller
    }()
```

Any further ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error handling has been changed, too.

```
fileprivate lazy var jobController : NSFetchedResultsController<AGJobData> = {        
   let request = NSFetchRequest<AGJobData>()
   request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "jobNumber", ascending: true), NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]
   let controller = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: AGDataManager.sharedManager.managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
   controller.delegate = self
   do {
      try controller.performFetch(&error)
   } catch {
      print(error)
   }     
   return controller
}()
```

It could be that you have to change the `NSFetchRequest` line to

```
let request = NSFetchRequest<AGJobData>(entityName: "AGJobData")
```

The literal string must be the name of the entity.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Did not expect solving answer so fast! Greetings from Munich!